# How can I wait for an Azure CloudQueue to be deleted?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage-queues

I am running some tests that use [Azure CloudQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue?view=azurestorage-8.1.3), and as setup/teardown I am calling [CreateIfNotExistsAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.createifnotexistsasync?view=azurestorage-8.1.3#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Queue_CloudQueue_CreateIfNotExistsAsync) and [DeleteIfExistsAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.deleteifexistsasync?view=azurestorage-8.1.3#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Queue_CloudQueue_DeleteIfExistsAsync). However when I am running my tests back to back I got a Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException,"The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict."

```
    await cloudQueue.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
    // do work 1
    await cloudQueue.DeleteIfExistsAsync();
    await cloudQueue.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(); // throws exception
    // do work 2
```

After taking a closer look at the server's response, I found the StatusDescription says **"The specified queue is being deleted."**

Is there a method that I can call so that once it returns, I know for sure the queue is already deleted?

=========================================================================
**UPDATE** Now that I think of it. If Azure Queue server wants to reply with deletion result, it will have to keep track of unfinished incoming request, which is obviously bad desgin (vulnerable to DOS attack)...

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a method that I can call so that once it returns, I know for
>   sure the queue is already deleted?

Unfortunately no. Deleting a queue (or blob container/table/file share) is an asynchronous operation. When you send a request to delete a queue, Azure Storage marks that queue for deletion (so that no operations can be performed on it) and then actually deletes the queue through a background process. Based on the documentation, it can take up to 30 seconds to delete a queue. However it may be more depending on how much data is held in there.

From the [`documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delete-queue3#remarks):

> When a queue is successfully deleted, the queue is immediately marked
>   for deletion and is no longer accessible to clients. The queue is
>   later removed from the Queue service during garbage collection.

**Possible Workaround:**

Since there's no method that you can call which will tell you for sure that a queue is already deleted, what you would need to do is try to create the queue using `CreateIfNotExistsAsync` and catch any error. If the HTTP status code is `Conflict (409)` and error code is `QueueBeingDeleted`, you should wait for some time and retry the operation. If you want, you can put incremental delay between retries.